# Delphi - How to check if a listBox contains specified string?

Tags: delphi

I have a listbox with items.I am looping through the listbox to get one item at once and to be assigned to a string variable.The question is.. Is there a way to check wether the list contains specified string? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
if ListBox1.Items.IndexOf('yourString') > -1 then
begin
  //whatever you want to do if your listbox contains 'yourString'
end;
```

Comment: +1 Why do you use `>`? The documentation says " If the string is not in the string list, IndexOf returns -1." The negation of `=-1` is `<>-1`. Now, I know this use of `>` is widely done, but it has always struck me as bizarre.

Comment: Of course you are right, even if this doesn't change anything. if a entry is found, as result you get the index of the string that is >= 0. Else you get -1. But yes, according to the docs you should check for <> -1.

Comment: I understand that `IndexOf` can never return a value < -1 but my point is not about correctness. Your code is correct. My point is about expressing semantic intent. I'm sorry to pick on you though, because this is something that I see from scores of Delphi  devs. You just drew the short straw!  ;-)

Comment: I suppose my point really boils down to this. How would we test for an item not being present? Would we write `IndexOf(ItemName)<0` or would we write `IndexOf(ItemName)=-1`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it has nothing to do with semantic intent.  Presumably the first thing you are going to do after determining that an object is in the list is to go ahead and index it.  If by whatever means `IndexOf` returns a value `<-1`, does it make sense to try to index it?  I consider the above to be a form of exception swallowing more than a deviation from semantic purity.  The difference is one of computer science and software engineering.  The most rigorous approach would probably be a `case` : `>-1` exist, `=-1` not exist, `<-1` exception, not expected.

Comment: I'd prefer " >= 0" or " < 0". Between comparisons with -1 i'd prefer "<= -1" and "> -1". If for any error or any future extension -2 woul became possible, i'd prefer to err on safe side with reduced functionality (false "not found") than on false "found string #-2" side. Other than that that really should not make any difference, even on CPU level ;-)

Comment: @Arioch'The There cannot ever be any other failure modes. Either a value is found, or not.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan there is no boolean property of IndexOf "value not found". So we had to deal with all the possible values of integer variable. Damn, even including local variable changed by the procedures we call.

Comment: @J... That would lead to a range error. The only failure mode is *not found* and that corresponds to -1.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So you will take care for our source at no charge if the return result will ever change? I like that idea :o)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ...assuming `IndexOf` always respects its contract.  It's not like bugs don't crop up from time to time or that the rules don't change, especially in areas where the rules are previously undefined.  There's nothing wrong with coding defensively, imo.  `IndexOf` returning `<-1` is not expected or defined so we should treat it as such.

Comment: @J... I think you have to code assuming that contracts are respected. Isn't that what a contract is? If you cannot rely on contracts then your code becomes paranoid. Do you start adding checks that the values of local variables don't change between assignment and reading? Just in case the computer is broken? Do you check that if `IndexOf` returns a value `>=0` then the value is less than `Count`? Do you double check that the value returned by `IndexOf` actually refers to an item with the specified text? So yes, I do like to rely on contracts!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, certainly.  In this case the contract only implicitly implies that it will not return values `<-1`.  I agree that substituting `>-1` for `<>-1` is incorrect, if only because it fails to then distinguish between expected and unexpected return values.  I'd say that `>-1`, if used, should be paired with handling of some sort for `<-1`.  `<>-1` will naturally lead to a range error where `IndexOf` fails by returning `<-1`.  `>-1` alone fails to detect such a failure.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OneBasedStrings was also a contract in delphi

Comment: @SirRufo A contract that was changed and a clear migration path provided. Clearly things change and develop.

Comment: yes, @DavidHeffernan , please do code in 2010 to the contract that would be made in 2020

Comment: I don't know why there is such discussion. Which one of you would test e.g. result of the `CreateEvent` Windows API function call success against `> 0` ? I hope no one...

Comment: The best would be to define a constant `const C_LIST_INDEX_LOW = 0` and check with `Result := AStrings.IndexOf(AName) >= C_LIST_INDEX_LOW;`

Comment: @David Heffernan:  Not sure why you would you want to rely on a "contract" when that makes your code dependent on the correctness of the documentation, which is frequently shown on SO to be wrong.

Comment: @MartynA It is impossible to program against a library without relying on a contract. We all rely on contracts all the time, hundreds of times a day.

Comment: @David Heffernan : maybe, but many 3rd party libraries have documentation which is perfunctory or verging on non-existent - where's the contract there?  Yet people manage to use them, because they know how delphi code tends to work.

Comment: @MartynA Of course there is a contract. The documentation may express is unclearly or even incorrectly. But the contract is still there. Everytime you use a library, or even write code in a programming language you rely on the contract.